# How use subquery in `in`?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I try create query with `in (subquery)`

```
sub = from(
    d in Deffered,
    select: d."ИД Категории",
    distinct: true,
    where:
      d.date_change >= ^date and d.deleted != true 
      and fragment("md5(Исполнитель) = ?", ^hash)
  )
from(
    a in Answered,
    select: {count(a."Номер")},
    where: a.answer_date >= ^date
    and a.deleted != true
    and fragment("md5(Исполнитель) = ?", ^hash)
    and a."ИД Категории" not in ^sub
  )|>Repo.all()
```

throw error:

> value `#Ecto.Query<from d in Dobrobot.Deffered, where: d.date_change
>   = ^"2018-11-19 00:00:00" and d.deleted != true and fragment("md5(Исполнитель) = ?", ^"6634F0A9A3C5EB7D97FBA08C1F08A45D"),
>   distinct: true, select: d."ИД Категории">` in `where` cannot be cast
>   to type {:in, :integer}

I can not find answer how use `not in` with subquery in google or chats

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [`Ecto.Query.API.in/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#in/2) documentation:

> The right side may either be a list, a literal list or even a column in the database with array type.

That said, the right side of `in` clause cannot be a query. The easiest solution would be to first get the actual list from `sub` with `Repo.all(sub)` and use this list. This leads to 1 extra query and IMHO is fairly acceptable.

Another solution would be to use `fragment` if the DB behind allows `in` with a `SELECT` statement.

---

This reference might also [shed a light](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#subquery/2).

Comment: Yes, now i do with extra query. But i can not understand why standard construction like `not in (subquery)` not added to ecto

Comment: `Ecto` is open source, if you need a feature `ecto` apparently lacks, feel free to submit a PR.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what changed when but this is possible now:

```
    and a."ИД Категории" not in subquery(sub)
```

Note that `sub` is *wrapped with* `Ecto.Query.subquery/2` and *without* the `^` (pin) operator.

[This has been documented as-of Ecto version `3.9.4`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#in/2):

> ...
>
> Additionally, the right side may also be a subquery:
>
> ```
> from c in Comment, where: c.post_id in subquery(
>   from(p in Post, where: p.created_at > ^since)
> )
> ```